# ASA Static Route over PPPoE interface

Tags: routing, cisco-asa, pppoe

I have an ASA5505 with two PPPoE connections.

I wish to add a static route to route just a single subnet over the new PPPoE connection, but the ASA does not seem to allow routing over interfaces without a next hop.

```
route inside 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 NewInterface

ERROR: % Invalid Hostname
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing to specify just an interface for a route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep this was a dumb mistake. Although PPPoE does not *have* to have a gateway, most still give a gateway IP address anyway. Once you know what it is:

```
route NewInterface 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 [GatewayIP]
```

worked just fine